# Getting all the directories using java program

Tags: java, java-io

How to get all the available directories in my computer (i.e., "C:,D:,E:,F:"... etc) in java. The program must also show the external drive directories If i plugin-in any USB drive... is this possible in java?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Wow what a requirement. I like it. Yes its possible.

Comment: Everything is possible if you just believe, and code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a windows environment, use listRoots() method.

```
File[] drivePath;

drivePath = File.listRoots();

for(File drive:drivePath)

    System.out.println("Drive Name: "+drive);
```

You can use a thread that refreshes every 2 seconds to check for any newly added devices. Complete this task and then you can try accessing system hardware directly to check newly added devices instantly